# Why dont we create an object of RemoteWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); ? why do we create it for WebDriver interface

Tags: remotewebdriver

I have seen few others also alsing the same question, but all the answers talk about remotewebdriver being used incase of grid set up. I understand we need to use it for grid .But why cant we use it for normal case also where code is executed on a single machine?

Can some please explain the reason?

Thank you

Comment: you can, but remote one will work for "normal" case as well as for grid case. why not making code more generic with no extra effort?

Comment: but i have not seen anyone use remotewebdriver in any of the project. Is there any specific reason ?

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use RemoteWebDriver more often than I use IWebDriver.
The reason for that is that RemoteWebDriver has the IJavaScriptExecutor interface, but IWebDriver doesn't and I often need IJavaScriptExecuter.

In most cases, it's best to use the least specific implementation that you need.
This makes the code more flexible, easier to unit test, and helps prevent conflicts.